# Is it possible to put an electronic seal on a document with OpenPDF?

Tags: java, pdf, openpdf

My company needs to implement a way to put an electronic seal on official PDFs to ensure their integrity. I have heard by some of my colleagues that it has been done with OpenPDF, but I have found nothing so far by searching on the Internet.

Is it effectively possible to achieve this with just using OpenPDF? Or do other libraries exist? In this case I would prefer free libraries, but if there are only commercial options I would like to try them first, so that I can see if I am able to use them and if my superiors want to take the economical risk.

This is the definition of e-seal from Wikipedia:

> A qualified electronic seal is an electronic seal that is compliant to EU Regulation No 910/2014 (eIDAS Regulation) for electronic transactions within the internal European market. It enables to verify the issuer of a document over long periods of time. Qualified electronic seals can be considered as digital equivalent to seals of legal entities on paper. According to the eIDAS regulation, a qualified electronic seal must be created by a qualified electronic device and based on a qualified certificate for electronic seal.

Comment: You should use the correct term in your question (and when searching or talking about it), you used to correct tag already: "digital signature", not a "seal".

Comment: There is no e-seal tag.

Comment: So are you talking about a *seal*, like a wax seal on a letter? Something that gets broken the first time you open the PDF so subsequent viewers know that someone opened the PDF before them? Then you should remove the irrelevant tag (if it really is not what you are asking about).

Comment: Yes, it's something like that. It's a new normative that ensures integrity of digital documents

Comment: *Integrity* can be achieved by a signature! A seal cannot be achieved, not without the PDF having a connection to a server and a custom reader for the pdf that behaves the way you want it to, basically you would no longer have a PDF but some custom 3rd party file format. How is this supposed to work even in theory with PDFs? Please think about what should actually happen, why and ***how*** that would ever work!

Comment: *"Conceptually similar to electronic signatures and usually technically realized as digital signatures, electronic seals serve as evidence that an electronic document was issued by a specific legal entity."* - so you want a plain and simple digital signature, that is it - period.

Comment: if you want to, there's an eBook by iText https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/digital-signatures-pdf/intro around Digital Signatures (the creators of the library iText, from which openPDF got forked from).

Comment: @Luca Did my answer help? Or are there still open questions?

Comment: @mkl I think it helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Seals and Signatures

First off, there were some discussions about electronic *seals* and *signatures* in comments to this question.

Legally (in the context of eIDAS) these are strictly different from each other. Technically, though, both are usually implemented as digital signatures, and in the context of PDFs more precisely as PAdES signatures; the main difference is in the signer certificates used which indicate whether you have an electronic seal or signature.

Thus, the question burns down to whether OpenPDF supports the creation of PAdES signatures.

#### OpenPDF and PAdES

OpenPDF is a fork of the last non-AGPL version of iText, i.e. the unofficial release iText 4.2.0 Bruno Lowagie tagged on 2009-11-27 13:59:39. In that year a first version of the PAdES signatures had just been published by ETSI as a technical specification (TS), not yet an European Standard (EN).

The iText library at that time, therefore, did not contain any explicit PAdES support, only for the interoperable ISO 32000-1 signature types. It offered the option, though, to mostly create the signature dictionary yourself and inject your own, custom-made signature container. Thus, by making use of this option, you could create PAdES signatures, and not only with the ISO 32000-1 compatibility profile but with the BES and EPES profiles, too.

The OpenPDF signature API has hardly changed since then; thus, there still is no explicit support for PAdES yet but the interfaces are open to inject signature dictionaries and signature containers to create signatures matching simple PAdES profiles (Baseline-B, Baseline-T, E-BES, E-EPES).

#### Concerning your questions, therefore

> Is it effectively possible to achieve this with just using OpenPDF?

It is possible with OpenPDF but depending on the exact profile you want you have to add some code to generate signature dictionaries and signature containers accordingly.

> Or do other libraries exist?

Yes. For example

- iText (from which OpenPDF forked long ago) meanwhile has been developed further and contains some more explicit PAdES support.
- The [CEF eSignature Digital Signature Services suite](https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/wiki/display/CEFDIGITAL/DSS) which for PDF signatures uses either PDFBox or OpenPDF as base PDF library but builds its own signature dictionaries and signature containers.
- ...

(For library recommendations, though, please use the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead of stack overflow, strictly speaking they are off-topic here.)